# Add timestamp to file sent on the response stream

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this piece of code,where I am trying to add a timestamp into the name of an excel file

```
resp.ContentType = "application/msexcel";
resp.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
resp.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=AllUsersList.xlsx");
```

I expect the file name to become something like `AllUserList_2016.xlsx`.

Comment: Where are you trying to set the timestamp exactly?

Comment: At the end of the filename. It should look like AllUsersList_2016....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the file name with `DateTime.Now` and the desired format.

For example, with just the current year:

```
string filename = $"AllUsersList_{DateTime.Now:yyyy}.xlsx";
resp.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment;filename={filename}");
```

Or with today's date:

```
string filename = $"AllUsersList_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd}.xlsx";
resp.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment;filename={filename}");
```

Or in the pre-C# 6 age:

```
string filename = string.Format("AllUsersList_{0:yyyy}.xlsx", DateTime.Now);
resp.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", filename));
```

Comment: What $ means there? It gives me an error because of it.

Comment: Oh, it is a new way of calling `string.Format` (since C# 6). I will change the answer to work with previous versions too.